# I can't not hide keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Help me, plz!
I can't not hide keyboard when changing one to another TextField.

I click on the "user" textfield pop-up Picker , click on a "Password" textfield , a pop-up keyboard, but if you click again on the "User" is not hide keyboard.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        userNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        userPasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == userNameTextField  {
        pickerUser.hidden = false
                   print("userNameTextField")

    } else {
        pickerUser.hidden = true
        print("@userPasswordTextField")
    }


}

@IBAction func userNameTextFieldStartEdit(sender: AnyObject) {

    userNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    userPasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    pickerUser.hidden = false
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the expected behavior - when you tap on a text field, it becomes first responder and presents the keyboard. Try adding a tap gesture recognizer to the view itself (your white background) and dismissing the keyboard from there using `view.endEditing(true)`

Comment: check my answer its work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code,

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == userNameTextField  {
            pickerUser.hidden = false
            print("userNameTextField")
            self.view.endEditing(true)

        } else {
            pickerUser.hidden = true
            print("@userPasswordTextField")
        }

    }


    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if(textField == userNameTextField) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return true
        }
        return true
    }
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Comment: Thank you! It's works, but first click on User textfield hide keyboard and only second click on User textfield pop-up picker

Comment: question: it's normal that only the second click pop-up a keyboard ?

Comment: This code working fine for me, then i click second time its normally show picker not show keyboard

Answer (score 2):

tyr only one line add in below:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

   if textField == userNameTextField  {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()      // this line add
       pickerUser.hidden = false
               print("userNameTextField")

   } else {
       pickerUser.hidden = true
        print("@userPasswordTextField")
   }


}
```

Comment: you add breakpoint and check this method call. this method doesn't call that you are set textfield delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that function you should call to hide your keyboard :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Instead of your `pickerUser.hidden = true`
And also:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

(Do you have that one ?)

Comment: Do you have a UITextFieldDelegate ?